# Need formula in newly inserted column to be the same cell reference as the preceding column but down a row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro in Excel. The macro needs to insert a new column just before the last column of a named range "K3_Entities" in an Excel spreadsheet. After inserting a new column it copies everything from the second-to-last column of the named range and pastes it into this new column. The code below achieves that.

```
Sub InsertColumn()
    Dim schSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    Dim newCol As Integer
    Dim namedRange As Range

    ' Set the worksheet
    Set schSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule")

    ' Set the named range
    Set namedRange = sch.Range("Entities")

    ' Find the last column in the named range
    lastCol = namedRange.Columns(namedRange.Columns.count).Column

    ' Insert a new column just before the last column of the named range "Entities"
    newCol = lastCol
    schSheet.Columns(newCol).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ' Copy everything from the second-to-last column of "Entities" to the new column
    schK2Sheet.Columns(lastCol - 1).Copy Destination:=schSheet.Columns(newCol)

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub InsertColumn()
    Dim schK2Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastCol As Long, newCol As Long
    Dim namedRange As Range, c As Range, cSrc As Range, frm As String

    Set schK2Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule K-2")
    Set namedRange = schK2Sheet.Range("K3_Entities")
    lastCol = namedRange.Columns(namedRange.Columns.Count).Column

    
    newCol = lastCol
    schK2Sheet.Columns(newCol).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    schK2Sheet.Columns(lastCol - 1).Copy Destination:=schK2Sheet.Columns(newCol)
    
    'adjust the formula
    With schK2Sheet.Range("K3_Entities")
        Set c = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1) 'Cell to be adjusted
    End With
    frm = c.Offset(0, -1).Formula                   'read the formula to the left
    Set cSrc = Range(Replace(frm, "=", ""))         'get the referenced range
    c.Formula = "=" & cSrc.Offset(1).Address(False, False, xlA1, True) 'offset by 1 row and create new formula

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Revise the formula with `INDIRECT` will get the expected output without extra VBA code

- Sample data of column B on sheet `Flowthrough` is as below
- Modify the formula from `Flowthrough!B46` to `=INDIRECT("Flowthrough!B"&(COLUMN()+43))`. The cell will display the same content as before. Adjust the `offset` (43) in the formula as needed, depending on the formula's location.
- The cell in the inserted column (col D) will get the expected result (from `Flowthrough!B47`)

[image]

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

> [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)